# how do i write a filter to get all the fields of the user 'tim' 's only

Tags: python, django

i only want all the questions, rank, and choice of the user tim

`x = AnswerModel.objects.all(user=tim)?`

```
class AnswerModel(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(UserModel)
    question        = models.ForeignKey(QuestionModel)
    rank            = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    choice          = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=CHOICE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have many option for this:

`x = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user__username__exact='tim')`

OR

`x = AnswerModel.objects.filter(user=
UserModel.objects.get(username__exact='tim'))`

Or you can do `get` as well which will throw exception if it gets multiple results or couldnot find the object.

See [Queryset API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/)